# How exactly does Rutherford's gold foil experiment confirm that the mass of an atom is concentrated at the Centre of the atom?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, scattering, history, atoms

I have been taught that the mass of an atom is concentrated of an atom, this can be proved by invoking the fact that very few particles are deflected. However, unless I'm mistaken the deflection is  primarily due to electrostatic repulsion. Therefore, couldn't we instead say that the charge density varies with radius such that it's mostly in the Centre, whereas the mass density is very low, and spread out through out the atom and get the same result?

I'd really  appreciate any help

Note:- Rutherford's gold foil experiment = Geiger–Marsden experiments

Comment: may I know why this question has received a downvote?

Comment: I'll make corrections, if the downvoter can point  out any mistakes in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric charge does not exist independent of particles with mass. This means that "charge density" will match "mass density" in Rutherford's scattering model. Furthermore, the alpha particles being used as probes in that experiment were highly energetic, which meant they had enough energy to penetrate the electron cloud surrounding the nucleus and "see" the bare nucleus as a scattering target. All of this is covered in Rutherford's own report on the experiment, which you should read.

Comment: oh,OK. Thank you,